# source doesn't recognize cwd?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

I have a bash script that sources a file, which sources another:

```
script.sh:
cd /script/dir
source funcs.sh


funcs.sh:
...
source mode.sh
```

Now this script runs OK when I run it from command line, from within /script/dir.
But when I run it from crontab, the funcs.sh file can't find mode.sh.
Probably because for some reason the `cd /script/dir` doesn't get passed on to it?
Is there anything I can do from within script, or do I need to cd in the cron or something similar?

Comment: How do you execute the script from your crontab schedule? Does the script not have a `#!`-line?  Depending on what shell is running the script (and how it's running it), the `source` command may or may not search the current directory for the dot-script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every process has a `$PWD` (working directory) cron does not run in your `$HOME`. Instead of `cd`ing in your script you can use this

```bash
#!/bin/bash

dir="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")")"
echo $dir
```

`$dir` is the location directory of a script. For example

```bash
$ cd /
$ bash /home/junaga/script.sh
```

outputs `/home/junaga` because that is the script location

Comment: From what's written in the question, it seems as if the initial `cd` command in the user's script succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

Possible problems:

1. There is no [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Examples) inside `script.sh`. If cron is told to run `script.sh` then it will run like `/bin/sh -c script.sh` (unless `SHELL` inside your crontab points to something else than `/bin/sh`, we don't know this). Since there is no shebang, this applies: [*Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/108618) The answer depends on what shell your cron uses, we don't know this for sure. Ultimately `sh` or something else may be chosen as the interpreter of the script. Even if `sh` is chosen, it may be provided by `dash`, `bash` or something else (in Ubuntu `dash` by default, but we don't know if it's really so *in your case*).

   The point is we don't really know what the interpreter of `script.sh` is, when the script is started from cron. I guess in some circumstances it may be the script cannot start from cron at all.

   OTOH when you run the script from your interactive shell, it's possible a different interpreter is chosen and then it works.
2. `cd /script/dir` may fail for some reason ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168908/108618)).
3. `source` is an alias for `.`, but not in all shells. Since we don't know the interpreter, we don't know if it understands `source`.
4. Even if the interpreter understands `source` as `.`, the argument is `funcs.sh` and it does not contain `/`. In such case the POSIX behavior of `.` is it searches for the file (`funcs.sh` in your case) in directories in `$PATH`. Now:

   - Even if your `$PATH` contains `.` (i.e. the current working directory), the same variable in cron probably does not contain it.
   - Only if search in `$PATH` fails, *some* shells try the current working directory.

To fix, do the following:

1. Use a shebang inside `script.sh`, so you are in control of what shell will be used to interpret `script.sh` when executed.

   (Depending on the shell you choose, the fixes (3) and (4) may or may not be necessary; they won't do harm, so if there is any doubt, apply them anyway.)
2. Abort if `cd` fails. If the script continues after `cd` fails then the script may try to source `funcs.sh` from a wrong directory.
3. Use `.` instead of `source`. The former is portable, the latter is not.
4. Use an explicit path containing `/` (in this case `./funcs.sh` instead of `funcs.sh`), so there is no search in `$PATH` and it's clear what file you mean.

The fixed `script.sh` will be like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
cd /script/dir || exit 1
. ./funcs.sh
```

Inside `funcs.sh` a shebang is not needed because this file is sourced by the shell interpreting `script.sh`, but fixes (3) and (4) may still be necessary (depending on the chosen shell).

Comment: (tiny comment: The `1` in `exit 1` is not necessary. With `cd ... || exit`, the exit status of `cd` would be used.)